# Twitter の認証コードが SMS で届かない

Tags: twitter

Twitterのデータを活用したプログラミング（Hobbies）を検討中です。
Twitterへのデータアクセスのためには、自身のアカウントに電話番号の登録が必要で、
電話番号入力後に認証コードがSMSメール送信され、その認証コードを入力すると手続きが完了するようです。

昨日から本件を試しているのですが、電話番号入力後、SMSメールが届きません。

今日改めて実施してもダメでした。以下は、調査済みです。

- SMSは受信拒否設定になっていないか？
  ⇒　なっていない
- 他のSMSは受信できるか
  ⇒　できる
- 認証コード入力以外の認証方法はないか？
  ⇒　ない。他の情報サイトでは、電話による認証コード連絡機能があるようだが、見当たらなかった
- 電話番号を国際電話指定にする
  ⇒　実施済み。081(日本）＋ 9051689999として、頭の0を抜いた電話番号を指定している

本件をクリアし、4種類のキー及びトークン（Consumer Key, Consumer Secret, Access Token, Access Token Secret）を取得することが目的です。

本事象の解決策をご存知の方おられましたら、アドバイスよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 国際番号は 81 ではないでしょうか？

Comment: ご指摘の通りです。国際番号は手入力する項目ではなく、リストから「日本（+81）」と指定する項目になっているので、誤入力はないと考えています。